# VS tools for C++ that are similar to the .NET tools?

Tags: c++

I'm writing in C++ again after primarily using C# for the past couple of years. I've grown quite fond of the refactorings from VS and CodeRushXPress in addition to searching by reference (i.e. tabbing on a variable takes me to every instance of that variable, but not others named the same). The VS "find" just won't cut it :D. Can people recommend any tools that will make me not miss C# as much?

Answer (score 9):

The best there is atm in Visual Studio is [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) and if you're a regular C++ programmer using Visual Studio it's well worth the money.

There are some signs that Microsoft got it together with Visual Studio 2010 but I believe it will take it a while to be as good as Visual Assist X has been for a long time now.

Check their [trial version](http://www.wholetomato.com/downloads/downloadTrial.asp), try it and see if it answers your needs.

Comment: Totally agree. It goes far beyond what intellisense provides you and eases not only refactoring but also browsing (view callees/callers quickly for example)

Answer (score 0):

VAX as recommended by daniel is a wonderful replacement for intellisense in C++ and also offers a few refactoring tools.

For some more refactoring tools, check out [Refactor! for C++](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/RefactorCPP/).